# Using Scrapy ItemLoader, parse first n characters of text from multiple elements

Tags: python, scrapy

Using Scrapy's ItemLoader, I'd like to parse the first n characters from an HTML element (which will have multiple embedded HTML elements, each of which may or may not contain text which constitutes part of the text that is to be retained).

Here's an example setup:

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="about-copy">
<p>Developers trust Stack Overflow to help solve coding problems 
  and use Stack Overflow Jobs to find job opportunities. We’re 
  committed to making the internet a better place, and our products 
  aim to enrich the lives of developers as they grow and mature in 
  their careers.
</p>
<a href='...'></a>
<p>Founded in 2008, Stack Overflow sees 40 million visitors each month 
  and is the flagship site of the Stack Exchange network, home to 150+ 
  Q&A sites dedicated to niche topics.
</p>
</div>
```

Parser code:

```
def parse_details(self, response):
   ...
   l = ItemLoader(item=Entry(), response=response)
   # this is presumably the portion of the code that is to be modified
   l.add_css('f_brief_summary', 'div.about-copy::text')
   ...
```

Desired result:

```
  Developers trust Stack Overflow to help solve coding problems 
  and use Stack Overflow Jobs to find job opportunities. We’re 
  committed to making the internet a better place, and our products 
  aim to enrich the lives of developers as they grow and mature in 
  their careers. Founded in 2008, Stack Overflow
```

Is there a one-step way to do this using an ItemLoader, or should the parsing be done manually, with the text then added to the ItemLoaded object with the 'add_value' method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the generic ItemLoader, create your own Loader class. You can then apply pre and post processing to each of the field, or define processors for them all. See: [Scrapy Item Loaders Guide](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html)

In your module which defines the Entry item, add the following. Notice that in the example below I am using the "remove_tags" method instead of "::text" in your selector.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Join
from w3lib.html import remove_tags


# You can do so much better here! 
def format_me(x):
    return x.replace('\n', ' ').replace('  ', ' ').strip()

# Here is the Loader you need to add; mine only covers one field. 
class EntryLoader(ItemLoader):
    f_brief_summary_in = MapCompose(remove_tags, format_me)
    f_brief_summary_out = Join()

# You already have this; mine only covers one field.
class Entry(scrapy.Item):
    f_brief_summary = scrapy.Field()
```

This gives you the result you wanted. To test:

Save your example snippet into a file, e.g. example.html

Run the scrapy shell

```
scrapy shell './example.html'
```

In the shell import your Item and Loader:

```
from scrapyproj.entry_module import EntryLoader, Entry
```

Test the parser:

```
entry_loader = EntryLoader(item=Entry(), response=response)
entry_loader.add_css('f_brief_summary', 'div.about-copy')
entry_loader.load_item()
```

Outputs:

```
{'f_brief_summary': 'Developers trust Stack Overflow to help solve coding '
                    'problems  and use Stack Overflow Jobs to find job '
                    'opportunities. We’re  committed to making the internet a '
                    'better place, and our products  aim to enrich the lives '
                    'of developers as they grow and mature in  their '
                    'careers.   Founded in 2008, Stack Overflow sees 40 '
                    'million visitors each month  and is the flagship site of '
                    'the Stack Exchange network, home to 150+  Q&amp;A sites '
                    'dedicated to niche topics.'}
```